# Can I customize section header in a UITableView? (font, image...)

Tags: ios5, uitableview

Can I customize section header in a UITableView? (font, image...)
I'd like to achieve something like this:

[image]

Is that possible?
I already got my cells like I wanted, but not section header.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a custom view for your tableView's section header by implementing the method `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // create and return a custom UIView to use for the section here 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will try it. But, what size, or height should I use? Do I have to create it by code? Can I use storyboard? Thanks!

Comment: I found this tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: so many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

NSString *sectionName = nil;

switch (section) {
    case 0:
        sectionName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Header Text 1"];
        break;
    case 1:
        sectionName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Header Text 2"];
        break;
    case 2:
        sectionName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Header Text 3"];
        break;
    }

    UILabel *sectionHeader = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40)] autorelease];
sectionHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
sectionHeader.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
sectionHeader.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    sectionHeader.text = sectionName;

return sectionHeader;
```

}